# How to pass sample size through a vector?

Tags: r, list, sample

I have a list and I want to have samples. The number of samples should correspond to the number in a vector. The problem is that he only takes the first number in sample_size for all list entries. 
I hope anyone can help me!

```
liste_mpg<-plyr::dlply(mtcars,"mpg")
sample_size<-c(2,6,7,1,4,8,9,0,7,9,3,4,6,1,8,4,3,2,6,7,4,6,9,1,4)
test_list<-lapply(liste_mpg, function(x) sample(x,size = sample_size))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` from `base R` to do the sampling based on corresponding elements of `list` and `vector` (or another `list`)

```
Map(function(x, y) sample(x, size = y), liste_mpg, sample_size)
```

---

With `lapply`, the issue is that it loops through the elements of 'liste_mpg', while the 'sample_size' is the full vector.  Instead, can loop over the sequence of `list`, extract the corresponding elements based on that index and do the `sample`

```
lapply(seq_along(liste_mpg), function(i) 
    sample(liste_mpg[[i]], size = sample_size[i]))
```

---

Or equivalent to `map2` from `purrr`

```
map2(liste_mpg, sample_size, ~ sample(.x, size = .y))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the multivariate version of `sapply`, `mapply`, instead.

```
mapply(function(x, s) sample(x, s), liste_mpg, sample_size)
```

or, simply

```
mapply(sample, liste_mpg, sample_size)
```